# Obtain Properties in Child Classes in IEnumerable of Base Class

Tags: c#, reflection

If I have an collection of a given entity, I'm able to obtain the properties for entity like so:

```
var myCollection = new List<Foo>(); 
entities.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetProperties().Dump();
```

However, I'm having some difficulties listing out the properties if my collection is an IEnumerable of a base class and populated with derived classes.

```
public class Foo
{
    public string One {get;set;}
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    public string Hello {get;set;}
    public string World {get;set;}
}

// "Hello", "World", and "One" contained in the PropertyInfo[] collection
var barCollection = new List<Bar>() { new Bar() };
barCollection.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetProperties().Dump();

// Only "One" exists in the PropertyInfo[] collection
var fooCollection = new List<Foo>() { new Bar() };
fooCollection.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetProperties().Dump();
```

Is there anyway to get the types of the items in the collection even though the collection is declared using the base class?

Comment: you have to get the type from the actual collection values by iterating rather than the compile time information.

Comment: What if the list has objects of different types? Why do you need the properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are obtaining the properties from the type represented by the type parameter `T` which is `Foo`, and `Foo` only has the `One` property.

To get all possible properties, you need to go through the types of all the objects in the list like this:

```
var allProperties = fooCollection
    .Select(x => x.GetType())
    .Distinct()
    .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  This is what I was looking for; I appreciate your help.